# Adjust every other row of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change every second row of my data frame.

I have a df like this:

```
 Node  |  Feature | Indicator | Value | Class | Direction
--------------------------------------------------------
1     |  WPS     |     <=    | 0.27  | 4     | 1 -> 2  
--------------------------------------------------------
2     |  ABC     |     <=    | 0.40  | 5     | 1 -> 3
--------------------------------------------------------
3     |  CXC     |     <=    | 0.45  | 2     | 2 -> 4
--------------------------------------------------------
4     |  DFT     |     <=    | 0.56  | 1     | 2 -> 5
--------------------------------------------------------
5     |  KPL     |     <=    | 0.30  | 3     | 3 -> 5
--------------------------------------------------------
6     |  ERT     |     <=    | 0.55  | 5     | 3 -> 1
```

I would like the following:

```
 Node  |  Feature | Indicator | Value | Class | Direction
--------------------------------------------------------
1     |  WPS     |     <=    | 0.27  | 4     | 1 -> 2  
--------------------------------------------------------
2     |  WPS     |     >     | 0.27  | 5     | 1 -> 3
--------------------------------------------------------
3     |  CXC     |     <=    | 0.45  | 2     | 2 -> 4
--------------------------------------------------------
4     |  CXC     |     >     | 0.45  | 1     | 2 -> 5
--------------------------------------------------------
5     |  KPL     |     <=    | 0.30  | 3     | 3 -> 5
--------------------------------------------------------
6     |  KPL     |     >     | 0.30  | 5     | 3 -> 1
```

So every second row changes the 'Feature' and 'Value' into the same as the row above, and the 'Indicator' is changed to '>'

I can't figure out how to iterate through the Dataframe (using iterrows I suppose) and changing only every second row?

EDIT:

I have tried the following as recommended:

```
    my_df = pd.DataFrame()
    my_df['N'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    my_df['I'] = ['=>', '=>', '=>', '=>', '=>', '=>']
    my_df['F'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

    my_df.loc[1::2, 'F'] = None
    my_df.loc[1::2, 'I'] = '>'

    my_df.fillna(method='ffill')

    print(my_df)
```

Output:

```
   N   I     F
0  1  =>     a
1  2   >  None
2  3  =>     c
3  4   >  None
4  5  =>     e
5  6   >  None
```

Comment: `df.iloc[1::2, df.columns.get_loc('Indicator')] = '>'`

Comment: Use     my_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

-- "inplace=True" parameter makes the changes permanent in the dataframe, else it is performed in a copy. Updated the code in original reply.

Comment: Otherwise you can try         my_df = my_df.fillna(method='ffill')

Comment: Oh great, yes that works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below is the logic used

- Select the even rows using slicing.
- Set the desired columns / fields with **None** for the sliced rows which need to be borrowed from previous row, we can fill it later using forward fill.
- Then use forward fill from last non null fields for respective columns

> ```
> import pandas as pd
> xlsColName = chr(ord('A')+colPosn)       # Get xls column name (not the column header as per data frame). This will be used to set attributes of xls columns
> df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
> df.loc[1::2, 'Feature'] = None           # prepare the field for use with df.fillna
> df.loc[1::2, 'Value'] = None
> df.loc[1::2, 'Indicator'] = '>'          # update the indicator field
> df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)  # This fills the NaN values from existing values
> ```

Comment: fillna() method of DataFrame scans rows from top, and when it finds a python  None value (equivalent to numpy.NaN) it replaces the None value with the last significant value from the same column.

Comment: You can refer pandas dataframe  documentation on "fillna" for more details.   I have tested the code, it works.

Comment: Yeah I read the pandas docs for filna, I guess there is some problem I can't see. I'll just keep trying to see what the problem is

Comment: I've tried it with a dummy Dataframe and it also doesn't work, is there something I am doing wrong? I will add to above code

Answer (score 0):

You an try something like:

df['Indicator']=">" if df['Node'] % 2 ==0 else "<="

This is if the 'Node' column is similar to and index.

Comment: I get the following error if I do this. ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Is your 'Node' column int?

Comment: Yes I just double checked it is